# Can Ehcache be used with SoftValue or other memory based expiration?

Tags: ehcache

I'm using ehcache for a lot of query-heavy operations, for example, different pages of data from the database is stored from different values of queries. I'm worried because the maxElements eviction seems useless for this, since the cached values may have drastically different memory sizes depending on the size of the objects returned from the queries.

I love the idea of a softValue expiration cache, where values are kept in memory as long as memory is available and then convicted otherwise, but I'm not sure if EhCache offers this functionality. But I can't imagine this being a unique use case, so is there other configuration I should look at?

I know Guava offers softvalue expiring cache, but I am not looking to switch cache libraries.

Answer (score 0):

With Ehcache you can configure how many bytes a cache can use in local heap memory (`maxBytesLocalHeap`). Have a look at the offical documentation ["How to Size Caches"](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/cache-size).